# Tidy, Clean Access To SKNodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I'm trying to tidy some of my SKScene code.  Currently I have about 11 references to SKNodes (some are layers containing sub-nodes).  These nodes and their sub-nodes are frequently accessed by the class.  The way I considered doing this is:

Subclass all the SKNodes to another class, for example, currently I have `layerPause: SKNode?` defined at the top of the SKScene.  This would become `layerPause: PauseMenu` where:

```
class PauseMenu: SKNode
{
lazy var lbBestTime: SKLabelNode = childNodeWithName("lbPersonalBest") as! SKLabelNode
}
```

Then, when the scene is loading I can simply use:

```
layerPause = pauseScene.childNodeWithName("pauseMenu")?.copy() as? SKNode
```

This would allow me to easily access important sub-nodes without calling `childNodeWithName` all the time.  But unfortunately, the PauseMenu class gives an error saying I can't use `childNodeWithName` method.

Could someone point me in the right direction?  Maybe there is a more elegant way to manage my nodes, or perhaps I'm missing something simple in the PauseMenu subclass as described above.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close, you just need to add an explicit `self`:

```
class PauseMenu: SKNode
{
    lazy var lbBestTime: SKLabelNode = 
        self.childNodeWithName("lbPersonalBest") as! SKLabelNode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All that's missing here is `self`:

```
class PauseMenu: SKNode {
    lazy var lbBestTime: SKLabelNode = self.childNodeWithName("lbPersonalBest") as! SKLabelNode
}
```

In the context of a (lazy) property initializer, you can't leave `self` implicit... probably that initializer is being treated as a closure (even though it doesn't require braces if it's a single statement), and closures always need to be clear about whether they capture `self`.

If you're initializing `layerPause` as in your question, and its type is `SKNode`, you still won't be able to use your newly defined `lbBestTime` property on it, though — all the compiler knows is that `layerPause` is an `SKNode`. Be sure to tell it that `layerPause` is a `PauseMenu`, and then you can use your custom properties from that class.

Comment: Indeed, I thought lazy initialisation might allow these properties but sadly it didn't.  Instead I added a layer variable to the class, removed the subclassing, and passed the node to the class via an initialiser.  It doesn't feel very elegant but it's an improvement on how it was before